# The purpose of (function(){})() in javascript

Tags: javascript, iife

What's the purpose of doing

```
(function(){
   console.log('holla at world');
})();
```

instead of

```
console.log('holla at world');
```

Is there an example where something has to be done using the first case.

Comment: [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
   console.log('holla at world');
})()
```

It's Immediately invoking function expression(IIFE) , the point of using IIFE's is to stop global scope pollution.